# How to efficiently show loading dialog if kotlin coroutine job takes quite some time to complete?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

What I want to do is to use kotlin coroutines for database operations and show users a loading screen in the meantime. My basic implementation is as follows:

```
fun loadSomeData(){
    mainCoroutineScope.launch { 
        showLoadingDialog()
        // suspening function over Dispatchers.IO, returns list
        val dataList = fetchDataFromDatabase()
        inflateDataIntoViews(dataList)
        hideLoadingDialog()
    }
}
```

This works perfectly for me when the loading takes quite some time for large datasets. But in scenarios where the `fetchDataFromDatabase()` finishes quickly, showing and hiding the dialog box in quick succession creates an annoying glitching effect.

So what I want is to show the dialog box only if the `fetchDataFromDatabase()` function take more than, *lets say*, 100 ms to complete.

So my question is, **what is the performance efficient way to achieve this using kotlin coroutines?**

Comment: I think it's more typical in a modern Android UI not to show a loading dialog, but rather show a spinner in the view where the data will eventually appear. This looks more graceful if the user backs out of the activity/fragment before loading is completed. You can also make the spinner view fade in over ~400ms, so if it is hidden very quickly, it won't look jarring.

Comment: @Tenfour04 dialog is just an example, I am using ghost views or spinners in most places, it's just for the conceptual purposes. You can think of dialog as for cases like database write operations or some blocking action.

Comment: What you want here is probably a `ContentLoadingProgressBar`. See the docs:  https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/widget/ContentLoadingProgressBar?hl=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I have achieved this, without using `!!` not null operator:

```
val deferred = lifecycleScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // perform possibly long running async task here
}

lifecycleScope.launch (Dispatchers.Main){
    // delay showing the progress dialog for whatever time you want
    delay(100)

    // check if the task is still active
    if (deferred.isActive) {

        // show loading dialog to user if the task is taking time
        val progressDialogBuilder = createProgressDialog()

        try {
            progressDialogBuilder.show()

            // suspend the coroutine till deferred finishes its task
            // on completion, deferred result will be posted to the
            // function and try block will be exited.
            val result = deferred.await()
            onDeferredResult(result)

        } finally {
            // when deferred finishes and exits try block finally
            // will be invoked and we can cancel the progress dialog
            progressDialogBuilder.cancel()
        }
    } else {
        // if deferred completed already withing the wait time, skip
        // showing the progress dialog and post the deferred result
        val result = deferred.await()
        onDeferredResult(result)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an idea:

```
fun loadSomeData(){
    mainCoroutineScope.launch {
        val dialogJob = launch {
            delay(1000)
            try {
                showLoadingDialog()
                coroutineContext.job.join()
            } finally {
                hideLoadingDialog()
            }
        }
        val dataList = fetchDataFromDatabase()
        inflateDataIntoViews(dataList)
        dialogJob.cancel()
    }
}
```

When you cancel the `dialogJob`, it should either hit the `delay` statement and prevent showing the dialog, or the `join` statement, which will cause the `finally` block to execute and hide it.

Comment: Regarding your opening sentence...isn't this only true if the `fetchDataFromDatabase()` function delegates to a background dispatcher context? I'm still learning coroutines, but I thought there is a unenforced requirement that any suspend function that isn't main-thread-safe should delegate to an appropriate background context. So the function needs to look like `fun fetchDataFromDatabase() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: You should always leave it to the suspendable function to ensure it doesn't block the main thread. As the caller you are guaranteed to be able to run it on any dispatcher, and as the implementor you are obliged to provide that guarantee. [The suspending convention](https://medium.com/@elizarov/blocking-threads-suspending-coroutines-d33e11bf4761)

Comment: I totally agree @MarkoTopolnik and @Tenfour04 that I should be switching to Dispatchers.IO in ```fun fetchDataFromDatabase() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { /*...*/ }```, I will update that in the question.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik your answer works but my first concern is the ```!!``` operator. Sure it won't be null but there should be a better way to do it without using that nasty operator :p

Comment: If you find a better way, be sure to let me know. Replacing it with `?.` would be a step in the wrong direction for me, a silent failure.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik can you take a look at my answer and inform me if there are any ill effects of my approach..??

Comment: @Ashu It introduces the extra complexity of double checking: `if (deferred.isActive)`. I don't consider it a good trade for just a benign `!!` that's guaranteed to succeed.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes it might add the complexity to the code but I tend to feel safer with extra code if I can ignore the `!!` check.

Comment: I understand that. In my view this is a deficiency in the library, the equivalent of `Thread.getCurrentThread()` requires a `!!`. However, I'd rather work around it with an extension function than by spraying complexity everywhere just to avoid ever touching the job of the current coroutine.

Comment: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/releases/tag/1.4.0 introduced the `CoroutineContext.job` extension property.

Answer (score -2):

The main purpose of loading dialog is to prevent user from touching the UI while loading, but there is no guarantee about that. There is always a chance user touches some button before the dialog pops up.

A better way to do this is just disable or hide the UI components, or in general, show a "loading version" of your UI.

It is better to let user cancel the loading instead of setting a short timeout, so you may still need a dialog or snackbar showing a cancel button, or you can make a task manager page in your app, that would be really complicated though.

Comment: maybe you got the wrong idea, my question is how to do it, not if I should do it. Besides, while loading a list of data, there is no problem if the user interacts with the UI. As pointed out in an earlier comment, the dialog is only conceptual. Your answer is more suited to be a comment, not an answer.